# Adding a class to a form validator

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, class

I'm looking to alter the following line of code for a form validator.

```
form.User.style.borderColor="#D3152C";
```

Rather than adding a style attribute, I would like it to add a class, but I'm not sure what the syntax would look like. Maybe something like this?

```
form.FirstName[0].addClass=("required");
```

Comment: What language are we talking about here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className) property (assuming JS from your question)

```
form.FirstName[0].className = "required";
```

Comment: This works great, thanks. I realized a simpler solution would be to change the original line of code to only the focus state of the element. Something like this:

form.User.style {{focus state only}} borderColor="#D3152C";